# How to destroy and reload a Model in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

Let's say I have a loop somewhere in my controller:

```
$continue = true;
while ($continue == true) {
    $this->load->model('foo');
    $this->foo->doSomething();
    if ($this->foo->someCondition() == true) $continue = false;
    unset($this->foo); //not working
    //if not continue to do it
}
```

inside this while loop, I need to create an instance of this `foo` model, it will continue to run, until some condition is met (which `$continue` will be set to `false`)

To make sure I create an instance of `foo` everytime inside this loop, I tried to use the `unset()` method (or setting `$this->foo = null`) to destroy the `foo` model, unfortunately it doesn't work (error msg: `Call to a member function doSomething on a non-object`)

Comment: why do you want to load inside the loop? is there any specific reason?

Comment: I need to create an instance of 'foo' inside the while loop so that inside I can to some initialization, and call some methods in 'foo' model. The above code is simplified, the actual code is more complicated.

Comment: which function doing initialization in model? Can you add model code also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`model()`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Loader.php#L231) method of CodeIgniter [`Loader`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Loader.php) core class, loads each *model* only **once**:

From the **[source code](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Loader.php#L264-L267):**

```php
if (in_array($name, $this->_ci_models, TRUE))
{
    return;
}
```

So, calling `model()` method, doesn't load the *model* again.

That's why you get the error: `Call to a member function doSomething on a non-object`

I'm not sure about what you're exactly looking for, But I'm pretty sure that you need to change your logic.

Comment: by looking at the source code it seems like it will never pop anything from the _ci_models array. So I guess I'll have to figure something out.

Answer (score 3):

Normally this isn't an issue because CI uses models as static classes, but while unit testing I found that if i created a mock of a model method I needed to reload the model afterwards.

first, extend CI_Loaded with MY_Loader in the file application/core/MY_Loader.php

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader
{

    /**
     * Returns true if the model with the given name is loaded; false otherwise.
     *
     * @param $name
     * @return bool
     */
    public function is_model_loaded($name): bool
    {
        return in_array($name, $this->_ci_models, TRUE);
    }

    /**
     * removes the model from the list of models
     * @param $model
     */
    public function unload_model($model)
    {
        if ($this->is_model_loaded($model))
        {
            $this->_ci_models = array_diff($this->_ci_models, array($model));
        }
    }
}
```

After that, in the unit-test code you can then unset the CI model.  by removing it from the _ci_models array, CI won't find it when trying to load.
So, the unit test setup would look like this:

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->CI = &get_instance();
    $this->CI->assets_model=NULL;
    unset($this->CI->assets_model);
    $this->CI->unload_model('assets_model');
    $this->CI->load->model('misc/Assets_model');
}
```